# How to get underline animation to only take up width of link?

Tags: html, css

[image]

Right now on hover the underline animation I've set up for my .nav extends past the link, and I want to make it so it only takes up the width of the link. The width is set to 100%, so I'm not quite sure why it's doing that. Also tried messing around with padding to see if that was the issue but didn't work. Could it be because of bootstrap?

```
html, body {
  font-family:;
  margin:0 auto;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  font-family: Roboto;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}

.nav {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0 auto;
  list-style: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding-top:0;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.nav > li > a {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  width:100%;
}

.nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color:transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav > li > a:focus {
  background-color:transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav > li > a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color:white;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.nav > li > a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
  width:100%;
}

.work h1 {
    border-left: 0px solid black;
    padding-top:30px;
    display:inline-block;
    left:50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:;
  }

.work a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.supporting .container-fluid {
  background-image: url("img/photo-top.jpg");
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  top: 0;
  width: ;
  height: 100vh;
}

.work .container-fluid {
  height:500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white);
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
}

.photography .container-fluid {
  height:500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: white);
  width:100%;
  padding:0;
}

.photography a {
    border-left: 0px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    left:50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color:black;
}

div.container-fluid {
  padding:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: calc(50% - 180px);
  width: 360px;
}

.info h1 {
  margin:0 auto;
  color:white;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.info a {
  color: white;
}

.info a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color:transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Create a fiddle please.

Comment: what's a fiddle?

Comment: update you html too

Comment: not sure what i'm being asked to do

Comment: Jsfiddle.net sample to share

Comment: Please post your full codes with html atleast.

Comment: We need to be able to reproduce the problem.